# What is the database symbol supposed to represent?

Tags: database

I know this isn't exactly a technical question, but I have never understood what is meant by the database symbol as a stack of nickles. I have a feeling this same question is going to be asked by future generations about the symbol for save being a floppy disk.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's an ancient storage mechanism called a disk, or more specifically a [disk pack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_pack). The nickels are the various platters. Or it might be an even more ancient one, called a [drum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drum_memory).

One of the nastiest sounds I've ever heard was when a computer operator (remember them, anyone?) put the protective cover on a DEC-10 removable disk pack before it had stopped rotating. But the best bit of operations centre madness I've seen was when my then boss walked into the computer room smoking a pipe. The fire system immediately went off - sirens and annunciators going "Danger, danger - Halon release in 30 seconds", "Danger, danger - halon release in 20 seconds" and so on. Someone had thoughtfully positioned  a  new cabinet in front of the halon abort button, so we had a few stressful moments there. Nothing to do with the question, I suppose, but it brought these memories flooding back....

Comment: This is actually exactly what I was asking! The symbology means nothing to me, so I am grateful for your input.

Comment: Shouldn't cloud storage be called "Drum computing" ?

Answer (score 8):

It's a stack of [Hard drive platters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drive_platter).

Answer (score 4):

You probably mean the stacked hard disk platters. This is the physical support for the database.